# How to Use Command Line Parameters in JMeter

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for testing APIs and I want to parametrize the project's path from the terminal and then I want to use this parameter in JMeter.

The parameter that I've sent via Command Line :

`./jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx -Jurl=abcdef.com`

The parameter that I've used in User Defined Variables :

`${__P(url)}`

But when I run my automation in JMeter, my test scripts are not going to URL that's been defined. When I check the request body, I see POST https://1 as URL.

Please see the attached photos.
https://mylifebox.com/shr/3df5bb35-cf43-4488-b20b-5c2d59656212&language=en

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start clean:

1. In the [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configure the variable with the name of `url` and the value of `${__P(url,)}`

   [image]
2. In the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)) put `${url}` into "Server Name or IP" field:

   [image]
3. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx -Jurl=abcdef.com -f -l result.jtl
   ```

   mind this [`-f` argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) which tells JMeter to overwrite the existing results file (it might be the case you're looking into "old" results where the `url` property value was starting with `1`)
4. That's it, you should see the HTTP Request sampler making a call to `abcdef.com` in the .jtl results file. And if you change this `url` parameter - you will see the impact in the .jtl results file:

   [image]

Comment: how to set result.jtl ?

Answer (score 1):

Put `${__P(url)}` inside [Server Name](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) field in HTTP Request.

> Domain name or IP address of the web server, e.g. www.example.com. [Do not include the http:// prefix.] Note: If the "Host" header is defined in a Header Manager, then this will be used as the virtual host name.

Don't use `User Defined Variables`

Comment: i did it as you say but nothing changed :(  Request body --> POST https://1:

Comment: @BuseKaya remove url variable from User Defined Variables