# How to execute Jmeter scripts based on the Environment parameter passed in command line

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to execute my Jmeter scripts based on the environment parameter passed on the command line. I have two environments Env1 and Env2, So if I pass environment parameter as Env1 on command line then the Jmeter scripts should execute for the URL configured for environment 1 and so on.

Can anyone help me with this work around?

Please note, I have implemented my Jmeter scripts using Maven project structure.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139762/how-to-use-command-line-parameters-in-jmeter

Answer (score 1):

1. In your [pom.xml file define a property](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), for example `environment`

   ```
   <properties>
     <environment>Env1</environment>
   </properties>
   ```

   this way you will be able to pass the `environment` property value via `-D` command-line argument
2. In [`<propertiesUser>` section](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#adding-additional-properties-to-propertiesuser) of the [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) define the same `environment` property:

   ```
   <propertiesUser>
      <environment>${users}</environment>
   </propertiesUser>
   ```

   this way you will be able to read the property value via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in your JMeter script like:

   ```
   ${__P(environment,)}
   ```

Above information should be sufficient for implementing your scenario, at least you can pass the URL directly via this property.